# Web Programming -> coordinate system

Tags: php, html

I need something like coordinate system that could be used on every image. And user can move objects in coordinate system and coordinates will be entered in text area. I'm not sure but I think JavaScript should be used.

Comment: You might want to give [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like [jQuery UI's `.draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) feature.

Through it you can let the user drag an object on the screen, access where it is, when it's stopped being moved, and so on. You can also drag according to ('snap' to) a grid.

Comment: Yeah, that exactly what I need. Thanks. Can you also help with getting X and Y ? Here is my code i need to get X and Y according to div containment-wrapper not the whole document?

`drag: function() {
var p = $("#draggable");
var position = $(this).offsetParent();
var xPos = position.left;
var yPos = position.top;
$(this).text('x: ' + xPos + 'y: ' + yPos);

}`

``<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div id="draggable" class="draggable">`

Comment: Try $(this).position().top instead of position.top (same idea for position.left). If that doesn't work, I'd suggest making a new question in stackoverflow for that. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Check the jQuery reference - you can lock the drag-area to a div or (almost) any other element. Check the [containment option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment).

Some code example from jQuery site:

```
// Initialize a draggable with the containment option specified.
$(".selector").draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
```